# layout de interface Java

Tags: java, swing, layout, front-end, gui

Estou desenvolvendo um programa para um amigo e estou usando a linguagem Java para isso.
Estou usando a IDE Netbeans que possui o recurso de construir a interface de usuário (UI) por drag n' drop, utilizando Swing.

Eu tenho muita dificuldade pra construir UI, sou muito bom no back-end, mas sou bem fraco no front-end.

Pelas especificações do meu amigo montei a UI dessa maneira:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Só que usei um Absolute Layout, e na hora que tento maximizar fica horrível.

Queria saber primeiro como posso desenvolver para uma tela Full Screen.

E quais são os layouts indicados pra fazer essa tela se não for pedir demais.

Comment: Já tentou o design livre?

Comment: como assim desgin livre?

Comment: Se eu não me engano, lá no prototipador do NetBeans tem uma opção de layout, acho que é "design livre", ele vem como padrão.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No Netbeans recomendo o [GroupLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/group.html). O IDE possui [excelente suporte](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/quickstart-gui.html) e o layout é bastante flexível (permitindo ancorar elementos, setar políticas para crescimento vertical e horizontal, etc). Você terá uma experiência muito parecida com desenvolvimento em IDES da Borland e Microsoft.

Tenha em mente porém que o código gerado para posicionar os elementos com `GroupLayout` será muito difícil de editar na mão. Se você quer mais controle eu sugeriria o [MiG Layout](http://www.miglayout.com/) que é suficientemente simples de usar manualmente, porém, poderoso o suficiente para a maioria das situações.

Finalmente, evite o [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html). Eis o motivo: [Totally Gridbag](http://madbean.com/anim/totallygridbag/).

Comment: Vou tentar Anthony, obrigado pela dica!